# Jayway JSONPath Expession for Both Object and Array

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, json-path-expression, jayway

I am having to trouble to retrieve value if parent element can be JSONArray as well as JSONObject. For that I used Deepcopy syntax to retrieve it. Now Problem is am getting additional values if child attribute exists in Inner Array also.

Eg:
JpathExpression:

```
$.store..book..innerBook..category
```

Result is :

```
[
   "innerReference1",
   "innerBook1Ref1",
   "innerReference2"
]
```

Example 1 Expected Result is :

```
[
   "innerReference1",
   "innerReference2"
]
```

Example 1:

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
        {
                "innerBook": [
                    {
                        "category": "innerReference1",
                        "author": "Nigel Rees",
                        "innerBook1": [
                            {
                                "category": "innerBook1Ref1"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "innerReference2",
                        "author": "Nigel Rees"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

Example 2:

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
        {
                "innerBook": 
                    {
                        "category": "innerReference1",
                        "author": "Nigel Rees",
                        "innerBook1": [
                            {
                                "category": "innerBook1Ref1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

Example 2 Expected Result is :

```
[
   "innerReference1"
]
```

Comment: It is working fine for Example 1...whereas for Example 2...it is retrieving value of innerBook1 category also...but ideally it should not.

Comment: Yes...from Example 1...InnerBook1.category is ignoring but for Example 2 InnerBook1.category is including in response.

Comment: Requirement is for both Examples ..need to retrieve only InnerBook category alone, because in Jpath Expression InnerBook1 not defined, because of Deep copy currently it is pulling value of innerBook1 category value also, Ideally it should not. I added Expected Results for Both Examples. Please look into it and if you find any solution, it will be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

A little late, however, we do not need to use recursive descent `..` after `innerBook` to walk the items in the array; with Jayway's we can use `innerBook[*].category` to retrieve the desired result for example 1:

```
$.store..book..innerBook[*].category
```

Example 2 requires to remove the array accessor:

```
$.store..book..innerBook.category
```

You cannot have `innerBook` as array and object in one JSON since it wouldn't be valid.

If you have an API (or so) that serves JSON with an `innerbook` property of  array or object type (which would be a badly designed API since the whole point of an API is to have expected responses) you could either query both paths or make the access of categories depending on the existence of `innerBook1`:

```
$.store.book..innerBook[?(@.innerBook1)]..category
```

Which only returns for both examples

```
[
   "innerReference1",
   "innerBook1Ref1"
]
```

Try it online [here](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is working fine for array object, but it is  not working for Json object whereas innerBook is an Object not an array. Can you please provide Jpath expression to get both jsonobject as well as jsonarray;

Comment: @MohammedAbdullah Glad to hear there is some progress; can you provide an updated sample to avoid confusion?

Comment: Added JsonObject Example, can you please help out to retrieve value using single Jpath Expression.

Comment: @MohammedAbdullah is this a theoretical question or do you use this somewhere?

Comment: @MohammedAbdullah As hinted, I think you need to run two queries to handle varied input. The following filter could help you to determine if query 1 or 2 should be used: `$.store..book..[?(@.innerBook[1].category empty false)]`

Comment: So its not possible to run in Single query, In My Current Application I can pass only one query(One JpathExpression) per Attribute.

Comment: Maybe someone else can suggest a oneliner but I don't see it right now. I might give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simpler example would be the following.

```
[
  {
    "title": "The Doe",
    "author": {
      "name": "John Doe"
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "The Does",
    "author": [
      {
        "name": "John Doe"
      },
      {
        "name": "Jane Doe"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I believe the JSON path we are looking for can return the names of all authors without a deep scan for name (i.e., `..name`)

Comment: Related GH issue: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/854

Answer (score 0):

It seems that JSONPath can't return your expected result using the same expression on both object and array.  You may try another JSON library *Josson* because it handles both object and array with the same expression.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Example 1**

```
Josson ex1 = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"store\": {" +
    "        \"book\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "                \"innerBook\": [" +
    "                    {" +
    "                        \"category\": \"innerReference1\"," +
    "                        \"author\": \"Nigel Rees\"," +
    "                        \"innerBook1\": [" +
    "                            {" +
    "                                \"category\": \"innerBook1Ref1\"" +
    "                            }" +
    "                        ]" +
    "                    }," +
    "                    {" +
    "                        \"category\": \"innerReference2\"," +
    "                        \"author\": \"Nigel Rees\"" +
    "                    }" +
    "                ]" +
    "            }" +
    "        ]," +
    "        \"bicycle\": {" +
    "            \"color\": \"red\"," +
    "            \"price\": 19.95" +
    "        }" +
    "    }," +
    "    \"expensive\": 10" +
    "}");
```

*Query*

```
JsonNode node = ex1.getNode("store.book.innerBook.category");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
//Output: [ "innerReference1", "innerReference2" ]
```

**Example 2**

```
Josson ex2 = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"store\": {" +
    "        \"book\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "                \"innerBook\": " +
    "                    {" +
    "                        \"category\": \"innerReference1\"," +
    "                        \"author\": \"Nigel Rees\"," +
    "                        \"innerBook1\": [" +
    "                            {" +
    "                                \"category\": \"innerBook1Ref1\"" +
    "                            }" +
    "                        ]" +
    "                    }" +
    "                " +
    "            }" +
    "        ]," +
    "        \"bicycle\": {" +
    "            \"color\": \"red\"," +
    "            \"price\": 19.95" +
    "        }" +
    "    }," +
    "    \"expensive\": 10" +
    "}");
```

*Query*

```
JsonNode node = ex2.getNode("store.book.innerBook.category");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
//Output: [ "innerReference1" ]
```

**Example 3**

Suggested by @thalhamm

```
Josson ex3 = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "[" +
    "  {" +
    "    \"title\": \"The Doe\"," +
    "    \"author\": {" +
    "      \"name\": \"John Doe\"" +
    "    }" +
    "  }," +
    "  {" +
    "    \"title\": \"The Does\"," +
    "    \"author\": [" +
    "      {" +
    "        \"name\": \"John Doe\"" +
    "      }," +
    "      {" +
    "        \"name\": \"Jane Doe\"" +
    "      }" +
    "    ]" +
    "  }" +
    "]");
```

*Query*

```
JsonNode node = ex3.getNode("author.name");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
//Output: [ "John Doe", "John Doe", "Jane Doe" ]
```